# Enlarging Check boxes in continuous form

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba

I am trying to increase the size of checkboxes through the use of wingdings by using this method.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()   
If Me.chkVerify = True Then   
lblLargeCheck.Caption = Chr(252)   
Else   
lblLargeCheck.Caption = " " ' a space
End If
End Sub

Private Sub lblLargeCheck_Click()
[chkVerify] = Not ([chkVerify])
If [chkVerify] = True Then
lblLargeCheck.Caption = Chr(252)
Else
lblLargeCheck.Caption = " " ' a space
End If
End Sub
```

Here is the error that i run into:
[image]

Notice the first check box is marked and the label check box has been all checked. Is there a work around this problem? I only want the large checkbox to be shown for a particular row only if the checkbox is marked. I will be hiding the checkbox at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tie the large checkbox to the `chkVerify` value in each row of your continuous form.  You can't do that with a label.  But you can do it with a text box if you give it this *Control Source* ...

```vb
=IIf([chkVerify],Chr(252),Null)
```

Then for `txtLargeCheck_Click()`, you only need to toggle `chkVerify` ... and that in turn updates what's displayed in `txtLargeCheck` ...

```vb
Private Sub txtLargeCheck_Click()
    Me!chkVerify.Value = Not Me!chkVerify.Value
End Sub
```

Here's a screenshot of my sample form in action ...

[image]